# How to get MQ Cluster information using Programmable Command Format?

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a mq cluster setup that has a few queue managers, some are full repositories and some are partial repositories.
A full repository is supposed to hold information(meta data?) about the entire cluster.
A partial repository will hold some information about the cluster.
**How do I gather information about the entire cluster using Programmable Command Format?** 
Information about hosts, queue managers, full and partial repositories, cluster queues etc....

**Update 1**
I have tried the following code but this does not return cluster information.

```
PCFMessageAgent agent = new PCFMessageAgent(queueManager);
agent.setCheckResponses(false);
PCFMessage[] responses;
PCFMessage request = new PCFMessage(MQConstants.MQCMD_INQUIRE_CLUSTER_Q_MGR);
request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQCA_CLUSTER_Q_MGR_NAME, queueManager);

responses = agent.send(request);
String clusterName = (String)responses[0].getParameterValue(MQConstants.MQCA_CLUSTER_NAME);
String clusterInfo = (String)responses[0].getParameterValue(MQConstants.MQIACF_CLUSTER_INFO);
logger.info("Cluster Name [" + clusterName + "]");
logger.info("Cluster Information [" + clusterInfo + "]");
```

The last line prints out a null.

**Update 2**
The answer below suggests that `MQCMD_INQUIRE_CLUSTER_Q_MGR` is equivalent to `runmqsc DISPLAY CLUSQMGR(*)` command. Following is the output from this command

```
display clusqmgr(*)
     4 : display clusqmgr(*)
AMQ8441: Display Cluster Queue Manager details.
   CLUSQMGR(QM_FR1)                        CHANNEL(TO.QM_FR1)
   CLUSTER(CLUSTER1)                    
AMQ8441: Display Cluster Queue Manager details.
   CLUSQMGR(QM_FR2)                        CHANNEL(TO.QM_FR2)
   CLUSTER(CLUSTER1)                    
AMQ8441: Display Cluster Queue Manager details.
   CLUSQMGR(QM_PR1)                        CHANNEL(TO.QM_PR1)
   CLUSTER(CLUSTER1)                    
AMQ8441: Display Cluster Queue Manager details.
   CLUSQMGR(QM_PR2)                        CHANNEL(TO.QM_PR2)
   CLUSTER(CLUSTER1)                    
AMQ8441: Display Cluster Queue Manager details.
   CLUSQMGR(QM_PR3)                        CHANNEL(TO.QM_PR3)
   CLUSTER(CLUSTER1)                    
AMQ8441: Display Cluster Queue Manager details.
   CLUSQMGR(QM_PR3)                        CHANNEL(TO.QM_PR3)
   CLUSTER(CLUSTER1)
```

I was expecting a similar response with PCF in the code i have supplied, but i don't get this information. 
So the question is 
**How do I get this information using PCF?** The above output is for a full repository queue manager.

Comment: I don't know how many ways I can say this. Remove the line from your code that is trying to print out the INPUT ONLY attribute MQIACF_CLUSTER_INFO and replace it with whichever of the Attributes on the page I linked you to that you need.  You have supplied the output from an MQSC command showing CLUSQMGR attribute, the CLUSTER attribute and the CHANNEL attribute. These can be found on the linked page in my answer, but to help you out, their PCF constants are MQCA_CLUSTER_Q_MGR_NAME, MQCA_CLUSTER_NAME, MQCACH_CHANNEL_NAME.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following PCF commands

- Inquire Cluster Queue Manager ([MQCMD_INQUIRE_CLUSTER_Q_MGR](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q087580_.htm)) which is the equivalent of the MQSC command `DISPLAY CLUSQMGR`. In the linked page, you can see all the possible output parameters listed in the section headed with `ClusterQMgrAttrs`. You can remove the line in your code that is trying to retrieve the value of the MQIACF_CLUSTER_INFO - an **INPUT-ONLY** parameter - and replace that line with any one of the parameters listed in that section to retrieve whatever information it is that you want about this cluster queue manager.
- Inquire Queue ([MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q087800_.htm)) with the MQIACF_CLUSTER_INFO parameter which is the equivalent of the MQSC command `DISPLAY QUEUE(*) CLUSINFO`. Please note, the MQIACF_CLUSTER_INFO parameter is an input qualifier to this command that causes cluster queues as well as local queues to be returned as answers.

As you correctly note, only the full repository queue manager knows everything about a cluster, so you need to make your inquiries against that queue manager in order to get the full picture.

Comment: I tried this, The MQIACF_CLUSTER_INFO parameter is only on the Inquire Cluster Queue Manager and the value returned in null. Any ideas?

Comment: I have updated my answer a bit. The CLUSINFO parameter is available on Inquire Queue. You can see this by issuing the equivalent MQSC command. When you say the value is null, what do you mean? The value or what was null? Do you mean you got zero responses back from the QMgr?

Comment: When I do a getParamterValue on MQIACF_CLUSTER_INFO I get a null value back. Printing to console prints 'null'. I am running this against a full repository QM. This cluster does not yet have any Qs but I presume the inquire cluster command should still work.

Comment: Like I said, MQIACF_CLUSTER_INFO is an input to the command - it is just there to tell the command to include cluster information. There is no output value for the parameter. The responses that come back from the queue manager will contain your responses. If you're unsure what kind of information you will get in your responses - try issuing the MQSC command (see my answer) that is the equivalent to the PCF comamnd you want to issue. If you're question is more than your originally asked, perhaps also update it to be clear what you want to know?

Comment: I think it is best to look at some code. I have updated my question and provided some code. Can you point out what is wrong with it?

Comment: runmqsc returns the correct information, but not able to get the same information from PCF.

Comment: That's because you are not looking at the correct output. I think I have said it three times now, but MQIACF_CLUSTER_INFO is INPUT ONLY. There really is no point in you looking at that as if it were output as you are doing in your code.

Comment: I have updated my answer to indicate how you should replace that line in your code.