# MQCMD_INQUIRE_CLUSTER_Q_MGR pcf request not returning cluster information

Tags: ibm-mq

Isn't `MQCMD_INQUIRE_CLUSTER_Q_MGR` is equivalent to `runmqsc DISPLAY CLUSQMGR(*)` command. Following is the output from this command

```
display clusqmgr(*)
     4 : display clusqmgr(*)
AMQ8441: Display Cluster Queue Manager details.
   CLUSQMGR(QM_FR1)                        CHANNEL(TO.QM_FR1)
   CLUSTER(CLUSTER1)                    
AMQ8441: Display Cluster Queue Manager details.
   CLUSQMGR(QM_FR2)                        CHANNEL(TO.QM_FR2)
   CLUSTER(CLUSTER1)                    
AMQ8441: Display Cluster Queue Manager details.
   CLUSQMGR(QM_PR1)                        CHANNEL(TO.QM_PR1)
   CLUSTER(CLUSTER1)                    
AMQ8441: Display Cluster Queue Manager details.
   CLUSQMGR(QM_PR2)                        CHANNEL(TO.QM_PR2)
   CLUSTER(CLUSTER1)                    
AMQ8441: Display Cluster Queue Manager details.
   CLUSQMGR(QM_PR3)                        CHANNEL(TO.QM_PR3)
   CLUSTER(CLUSTER1)                    
AMQ8441: Display Cluster Queue Manager details.
   CLUSQMGR(QM_PR3)                        CHANNEL(TO.QM_PR3)
   CLUSTER(CLUSTER1)
```

I was expecting a similar response with PCF in the code i have supplied, but i don't get this information.
I have tried the following code but this does not return cluster information.

```
PCFMessageAgent agent = new PCFMessageAgent(queueManager);
agent.setCheckResponses(false);
PCFMessage[] responses;
PCFMessage request = new PCFMessage(MQConstants.MQCMD_INQUIRE_CLUSTER_Q_MGR);
request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQCA_CLUSTER_Q_MGR_NAME, queueManager);

responses = agent.send(request);
String clusterName = (String)responses[0].getParameterValue(MQConstants.MQCA_CLUSTER_NAME);
String clusterInfo = (String)responses[0].getParameterValue(MQConstants.MQIACF_CLUSTER_INFO);
logger.info("Cluster Name [" + clusterName + "]");
logger.info("Cluster Information [" + clusterInfo + "]");
```

The last line prints out a null.

So the question is 
**How do I get this information using PCF?** The above output is for a full repository queue manager.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get MQ Cluster information using Programmable Command Format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242592/how-to-get-mq-cluster-information-using-programmable-command-format)

Answer (score 0):

The following code displays the required information:

```
        responses = agent.send(request);
        for(int i=0; i < responses.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Cluster Queue manager [" + (String)responses[i].getParameterValue(MQConstants.MQCA_CLUSTER_Q_MGR_NAME) + "]");                                  
            System.out.println("Cluster Name [" + (String)responses[i].getParameterValue(MQConstants.MQCA_CLUSTER_NAME) + "]");
            System.out.println("Cluster Channel [" + (String)responses[i].getParameterValue(MQConstants.MQCACH_CHANNEL_NAME) + "]");                                    
        }
```

The output looks like this:

```
Cluster Queue manager [QM1                                             ]
Cluster Name [CLUS1                                           ]
Cluster Channel [TO.QM1              ]
```